# Used powershell to export csv files, these are all strings, need to upload to sql server as ints

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, export-to-csv

Interesting problem here, I created a series of csv files, all with differing content, using powershells export-csv utility. This, as I've learned exports a csv file, in which all values are strings, and are thus encapsulated by quotation marks. This is a problem because the fields all have different type values, including ints, doubles etc. I need to be able to import these into SQL Server, and the quotes pose a problem when attempting to insert into fields with those types.

I have considered removing all the quotes using regex, and perhaps using a different delimiter, such as a pipe, but the problem with this approach is that some of the other fields are items such as emails, which may have quotation marks in them which need to remain.

I have also toyed with the idea of exporting to xml via clixml, however, I need the person importing the data to be able to avoid complex import methods such as SSIS.

Any suggestion is a good suggestion, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

What are they going to use to import the data, and how does that program recognize strongly typeed data?

I can type csv data in Powershell by specifying the typecast as part of the string, and then re-casting it by invoking that expression on re-import:

```
$ht = @{
Prop1 = "[int]21"
Prop2 = "[datetime]'07/18/2011'"
Prop3 = "[double]31"
}

$x = new-object psobject -property $ht
$x | export-csv testtype.csv -notype

$y = import-csv testtype.csv 
$props = $y.psobject.properties | select -expand name


$y |% {
foreach ($prop in $props){$_.$prop = iex $_.$prop}
}
```

How does whatever you're using to do the import recognize data types?  Can you add a typecast to the string in a format that program recognizes?

Comment: Yikes. That makes it a very brittle CSV for anything else, actually. If you need a typed PowerShell-only dump format, then CLIXML is probably better.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that there are over 300 of these csvs that will need to be uploaded, and the data in the csvs will differ from month to month. Therefore typecasting really isn't feasible...

Comment: Also, Joey, is there an easy way to import the xml doc if I chose to do it that way?

Comment: @joey - I understand it's "brittle". It was intended to demonstrate using explicit typecasting in the string. If it's all within powershell you can use clixml, or just keep the typeinfo header. @ user823694 - you seem to have mutually exclusive objectives.  You want strongly typed data, but don't want to strongly type the data.

Comment: That's a nice way of saying it ;)

Comment: No, no, I don't need it strongly typed, I just need for numbers to not be encapsulated by double quotes.

Comment: as the issue i'm having, to be exact, is that sql cannot convert values within quotes to numerical fields.

Comment: @user: I gave you a simple command to post-process in my answer to your last question already.

Comment: You did, however, that won't work for my case as there is a small chance that the regex expression might appear in an email and break it, hence why I made another post, asking, in a non-leading manner, for a solution.

Comment: So, what I have come up with now is to delimit the csv using "|" and now I am trying to write a -replace statement in powershell that will allow me to simply replace the pipe and the two quotation marks directly next to it with just a pipe, what I have come up with is \"\|\" which definitely works, only problem is putting it in the replace, maybe I'm just being dumb, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get that to be a string.